# JUnit 5 @WebFluxTest test to a Flux @PostMapping using WebTestClient

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-webflux

I'm trying out Spring WebFlux using annotation controller and embedded mongodb (JDK11). I am trying to write `@WebFluxTest` for my `@RestController`, in particular, `@PostMapping` portion.

It's a just basic setup with `@RestController`, and `@Repository`.

In my `@RestController`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/address")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AddressController {

    private final AddressRepository addressRepository;

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping(value = "/create")
    public Flux<Address> create(@RequestBody Flux<Address> address) {
        return address.flatMap(this.addressRepository::save);
    }
}
```

In my test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest(AddressController.class)
public class AddressControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @MockBean
    private AddressRepository addressRepository;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Create")
    public void create() {

        Flux<Address> addresses = Flux.just("Hello").map(add -> 
                            Address.builder().id("5bf907ff2e21d401d4054a4d").street(add).build());

        Address add = Address.builder().id("5bf907ff2e21d401d4054a4d").street("Hello").build();

        when(this.addressRepository.saveAll(addresses)).thenReturn(addresses);

        this.webTestClient
            .post()
            .uri("/address/create")
            .body(addresses, Address.class)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isCreated()
            .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .expectBody(Address.class).isEqualTo(add);
    }
}
```

And a very simple POJO:

```
@Data
@Builder
@Document
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Address {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String street;
}
```

Question:

I want to be able to create the endpoint to allow creation of `0..*` address.

How to correctly write the unit test so that I can `mock` the call in `create()`? If I do

```
when(this.addressRepository.save(add)).thenReturn(addresses);
```

then, it's a `Mono`

But if I do

```
when(this.addressRepository.saveAll(addresses)).thenReturn(addresses);
```

then it's not `mocking` the correct method call in `create()`.

What is the correct way to write this unit test?

Thanks! If I didn't provide enough info, please let me know.

Update: I am able to `create` using `Postman` to my `/address/create` endpoint though.

Comment: I haven't read the whole the question, because it's way too long and actually asks several different things, which should be in separate questions. But your controller calls save(), and your test mocks saveAll().

Comment: I have clean up my question to only focus on the unit test now. I understand that, but when I call save() in my mock, it will complain that it is not a `Flux`. Do let me know how I can properly write the unit test so that I can test my endpoint. The confusing portion would probably be because I will doing a `flatMap` before calling the `save()`. So an example on how to write a proper test will be appreciated.

Comment: save() returns a Mono. But you tell your mock to return a Flux.

Comment: Precisely, I want to return a `Flux` because my endpoint can take a `Flux`. So it can take on `0..*` Addresses, save it to `Repository` and then return the result back. What I am not sure is, how can I write the unit test for it. So please do show me an example on how I can achieve it.

Comment: That is irrelevant. You're mocking your repository's save() method. save()'s return type is Mono. Not Flux. So when you tell your mock what to return when save is called, it must be a Mono, not a Flux.

Comment: Which is to say that I have done wrongly, and I have no idea what should be the right way to do so. So if you could just show me a simple example, then I can learn. I understand your sentence of `save()` returning a `Mono` instead of `Flux`. As my `create()` method does a `flatMap` to save the `Address`, how do I even mock this portion in my unit test? If I perform `save()`, it's a `Mono`, if I don't but my `create()` is calling `save()`, so what should I do? This is what I don't understand, and trying to do. I have updated my question to make it even clearer now.

Comment: You don't mock the code you're testing. What you mock is the dependency of the code you're testing, i.e. the repository. You want to tell the repository: when your save method is called, please return this Mono. But what you're doing is: when your save method is called, please return this Flux. So replace `.thenReturn(addresses)` by `.thenReturn(Mono.just(theAddressThatTheRepositoryMustReturnInAMono)`. I think you should step back a little, and learn the principle of mocks and stubs, before diving into WebFlux and reactive programming, which is **hard**.

Comment: I got it working anyhow with some tweaks. Thanks anyway.